# How to swaplevel for certain columns (but not all) in multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multilevel dataframe for which I'd like to drop two of the items from the multilevel index from their top row index (level 0) down to the level 1 index so that I can then swing the full top level 0 and set it as the vertical index.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
newyork2 = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/thedatasleuth/New-York-Congressional-Districts/blob/master/newyork2.csv?raw=True")

newyork2.columns.get_level_values(0) #As you can see, 'Party' and 'Year' are part of this level - these are the columns I want to drop to level 1.

newyork2.columns.get_level_values(0)[0].swaplevel(0,1) # This breaks
```

Comment: I think it might be: `ny3 = newyork2.swaplevel(0,1, axis='columns')`

Comment: I think your 'read_csv' command is missing some options. As is, the index and columns each have 1 level.

Comment: When you read the file, only the first row is in the header so it is NOT a multilevel index with respect to the columns.  Pass `headers=[0, 1]` to the `read_csv` function.

Comment: so some example output of what you want, the question isn't clear.

Comment: Correction:  `header=[0, 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really hard to tease out what you want from your question. It sounds like you might want to stack the dataframe when you say:

> so that I can then swing the full top level 0 and set it as the vertical index

```
import pandas

url = "https://github.com/thedatasleuth/New-York-Congressional-Districts/blob/master/newyork2.csv?raw=True"

newyork = (
    pandas.read_csv(url, header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1, 2])
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .stack(level='DISTRICT')
        .rename_axis(['PARTY', 'YEAR','DISTRICT'], axis='index')
)
```

And I get:

```
STATUS                 Active  Inactive     Total
Party Year DISTRICT                              
DEM   2014 1         134293.0    9029.0  143322.0
           10        241859.0   29860.0  271719.0
           11        181049.0   10798.0  191847.0
           12        245977.0   35086.0  281063.0
           13        314229.0   37961.0  352190.0
           14        199060.0   17156.0  216216.0
           15        265862.0   29801.0  295663.0
           16        239335.0   22452.0  261787.0
           17        185510.0   13949.0  199459.0
           18        145155.0   12118.0  157273.0
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your interest and help - these were all great answers, but this answer is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!